# Как сделать чтобы кнопку, которая будет влиять на содержимое другого блока?

Tags: html, css

Хочу реализовать на сайте страницу точки продаж: сверху высокий блок с Гугл (Яндекс) картой, под ним 3 коротких блока в колонку с описанием конкретных магазинов. в каждом из описании есть кнопка "показать адрес".

1. как реализовать по нажатию на эту кнопку смену встраиваемой карты? (не обязательно на примере карты, в примере прикрепил код, подчеркну, задача в том, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку изменялся сам блок, а не его цвет)
2. отдельно буду признателен, если реализация подойдёт для n-ого количества магазинов, т.е. автоматически будет высчитываться порядковый номер кнопки и относительно него будет отображаться контент в блоке.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.shop {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
color: #fff;
}

.shop-1 {
background: red;
}

.shop-2 {
background: blue;
}

.shop-3 {
background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop shop-1">1</div>
<div class="shop shop-2">2</div>
<div class="shop shop-3">3</div>
<button class="shop__btn shop__btn-1">показать 1</button>
<button class="shop__btn shop__btn-2">показать 2</button>
<button class="shop__btn shop__btn-3">показать 3</button>
```

Comment: Вы явно описываете то, что нужно делать на JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Вам не надо 3 блока `<div class="shop shop-n"></div>` достаточно одного, в котором в зависимости от нажатой кнопки будет загружаться нужный адресс.

2)Кнопки лучше делать обезличеными, например `<button type="button" class="shop__btn" data-map="0">показать 1</button>`

3)Дальше пишете код подгрузки 'iframe' карты. У гугла они платный, и нуждаються в подключении [API ключа](https://art-lemon.com/google-maps-api-key)()

4)После того как добьетесь того что карта у вас уже показываеться(хоть какая-то), просто создаете массив из переменных, в которых храняться координаты магазинов, и тогда в зависимости от `data-map` кнопки заменяете `iframe` в нужном блоке. `data-map => индекс в массиве`

Comment: я только начал учить js, был бы очень благодарен, если бы вы на этом примере подсказали мне, как это реализовать в виде кода. а то нагуглить не получается:) в остальном спасибо большое за ответ - логику предельно ясно расписали!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgwhiHLu2H4 Материала полно. Это слишком заезженая тема. На каждом 1-ом магазине вставляют карту маршрута. Программирование - это в первую очередь поиск информации. Ну или 50$ и за вас этот код готовы написать.